# How to align query in sqldeveloper 4.0?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have query written in sqldeveloper but I don't know how to align or format the query in neat order.

P.S: I don't know whether this question can be asked here. Kindly answer if any knows the answer here.

Comment: I think you must go to preferences->oracle formatting (or something like this) to set your format preferences and after that, use ctrl-f7 to format your query

Comment: thanks leo that's what i was looking at.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f7</kbd> to format or align my query in sqldeveloper 4.7 with reference to the above comment from leo.

Answer (score 19):

Just right click, select `FORMAT` option, or, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f7</kbd> shortcut to format. If you have not set your own formatting rules, then it would take the default formatting.

If you want to configure your own formatting, not many options though, go to **`Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Display`**

You can also save it as your default format. So that even if you reinstall `SQL Developer`, you can always point to the format file you saved earlier in your local machine.

Answer (score 7):

right click on the query and then select "format"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

The steps I followed were:

```
Goto Tools > Preferences > SQL Formatter
```

Then Click Export and save the xml file. Now make changes however you like.
Eg- I wanted 4 commas per line, so changed all 1 to 4 and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f7</kbd> to format.

Works well.

Answer (score 3):

For windows, CTRL + F7

For Mac, there is nothing from the OOTB. However, you can setup custom shortcut keys.
`Preference -> Shortcut Keys`. Search for '***format***' and assign the new shortcut key.